# Adding a track to Playlist

Tags: android, playlist, audio-player, android-music-player

I have searched a lot but couldn't find. Is there any way to add a song to Android playlist programmatically? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
public class TestAddTrack extends Activity {


private MediaPlayer mp = null;
private List<String> playList = new ArrayList<>();
private int indexPlay = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    playList.add("Sugar Maroon 5 - Maroon 5.mp3");
    playList.add("We Don t Talk Anymore - Charlie Puth Selena Gomez.mp3");
    playList.add("Why Not Me - Enrique Iglesias.mp3");

    initNewMediaPlayer();
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                initNewMediaPlayer();
            }
        });
    }
}

private void initNewMediaPlayer() {
    if (indexPlay <= playList.size()) {
        String songName = playList.get(indexPlay);
        ++indexPlay;

        if (songName.isEmpty()) {
            initNewMediaPlayer();
        } else {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Music/" + songName));
            mp.setLooping(false);
            mp.start();
        }
    }
}
```

and don't forget permission if you use external.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I was asking about the playlists that we create using ContentResolver like Favorite, Last Played playlists that come in any new music player app ?